# Linking to fftw3.h in C++ source file for R package

Tags: r, r-package

I have some C++ code that I intend to export into my r package using Rcpp. However, this code links to [fftw3](https://www.fftw.org/) via

```
#include <fftw3.h>
```

at the top of the file. When I try to compile this code, I unsurprisingly get the error

```
fatal error: 'fftw3.h' file not found
```

What is the proper way to link to this file so that it will be available upon compilation of my package? I know that a Makevars file can generally be used to link to system libraries but since this library is external I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks,

Eric.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the Rcpp vignette [Rcpp libraries](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-libraries.pdf) -- which is also this [arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06416).

There are many examples among the 2400+ CRAN packages using `Rcpp`.  My hunch would probably be to look at what I contributed to the `nloptr` package -- even though that is a more complicated scheme where we allow use *either* a system library if present (could be the case with `fftw3` too) *or* downloand and build.

Rcpp has been used *a lot* to build such glue.  The most common, and simplest , approach is to look for `pkg-config` and query it for headers and libraries.  Please give that a shot (with some looking around CRAN or GitHub for examples).

*Edit:* There is also an (old) `fftw3` package by Gabor [at his previous employer's GitHub org](https://github.com/MangoTheCat/fftw3) as well as another [CRAN package `fftwtools`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=fftwtools) (which, if memory served, I helped once too but I don't recall now what for).